Can I have two pumps on one well?
Can I install two pumps from one well? I would like to have a sprinkler pump and a domestic water pump draw from the same well.

This depends on what type of well pump you currently have.  If your current pump is a submerged pump, you cannot add another pump.  If your pump is surface mounted, (Highly unusual) you may be able to plumb in a line for another pump.  There are still other considerations, like pipe sizing, volum need for irrigation, etc.

And water rights - don’t forget about water rights…

Also, what is the maximum amount of water the well can provide in continual use? If the irrigation pump, for example, pumps water below the level of the domestic water pump, it's not helpful. A pump run dry may seize.

@RMDman Citation needed. I believe the only limitation is whether it fits in the well bore.

@User, If it works for you, ok. In my area you cannot piggyback submerged pumps. In rare instances and if the well casing is wide enough there can be a tandem pump system. However these are usually never used in residential single home systems.

@RMDman Ok, give a regulation then. Citation needed.

@user, look up your own citation.  I just know from experience working with well drillers for my condo, that piggybacking is not allowed .  Asked the question, got the answer from the licensed pro and I didn't ask him to quote me the  regulation.

@Jon Custer, Correct, Another issue on our condo's well was the volume of water to be pumped.  We also need to conform to SWFWD regulation. The OP may have similar.
